# Why didn't they design array index to start from 1?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

In many programming languages, the array index begins with 0. Is there a reason why it was designed so?

According to me, it would have been more convenient if the length of the array was equal to the last index. We could avoid most of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exceptions.

I can understand when it comes to a language like `C`. `C` is an old language and the developers may have not thought about the issues and discomfort. But in case of modern languages like java, they still had a chance to redefine the design. Why have they chosen to keep it the same?

Is it somehow related to working of operating systems or did they actually wanted to continue with the familiar behaviour or design structure (though new programmers face a lot of problems related to this)?

Comment: Already asked. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm

Comment: Sounds like you need to go to the pub with a FORTRAN and a C programmer, and settle it like men. By the way, FORTRAN - with its 1-based arrays - is older than C.

Comment: It's a bit like asking why US buildings use 1-based floor numbering, whereas European buildings use 0-based floor numbering, or why there are 14 types of mains electrical plug recognized by the IEC. Different people picked different conventions a while ago, and those conventions stuck in their respective domains.

Comment: @Bathsheba fitting, as earlier cultures didn't grasp the concept of `0` - they're all dead now...

Comment: Also: https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: How is this question opinion-based? The answer, imo, is very clear and "non-debatable". This should be re-opened or closed as a duplicate if there is one (in SO).

Answer (score 6):

An array index is just a memory offset.
 So the first element of an array is at the memory it is already pointing to, which is simply
`*(arr) == *(arr+0)`.

Comment: I wish everyone learned assembly first and understood offsets.